# Exclude property from MVC Viewmodel in MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have Classes  as

```
public class Restaurant
{
    [Key]        
    public int RestId { get; set; }
    public string RestName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Pincode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RestaurantReviews>Reviews { get; set; }


}

public class RestaurantReviews 
{
    [Key]
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public int RestId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Review { get; set; }        
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }          


}
```

Now I have created View Model as

```
public class ViewRestReviews 
{
    public Restaurant restaurants{ get; set; }        
    public RestaurantReviews restaurantreviews { get; set; }

}
```

I am using this ViewModel for updating Record as

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditReview(ViewRestReviews model)
    {

       // TryUpdateModel(model, excludedpro: new[] { "FirstName" });
        ModelState.Remove("Rating");
        TryUpdateModel(model);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                               
            ObjEntity.Entry(model.restaurantreviews).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ObjEntity.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Review", new { RestId = model.restaurantreviews.RestId });

        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Now My question is I dont want that end user can edit 'Rating'. For this I have use the EXclude attribute on class([Bind(Exclude = "Rating")]) and even on the actionMethod. I use excluded.But nothing works for me... Please help me out how to exclude property from VIEWMODEL. THANKS in ADVANCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rebind the Model , so i think it will work for you 
if you need any help ,please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have View specific Models (ViewModel), instead of having shared models between different views.

So Create a separate model for Edit Review Action where it does not have 'Rating' property.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Is there any way to do this in ViewModel? or any better approach....

Comment: Having Separate Model is the standard practice. There are some option where you have to explicitly remove it from Model, once you bind the Model. But those are not really the good options.